# Identify rman files and delete them

Tags: oracle, rman

I need to clean up space and do a full backup of database.

Old backups are safe on tape.

My backups are on 2 specifics directories (2 channels).

So I did:

```
DELETE EXPIRED BACKUP;
DELETE OBSOLETE;
DELETE BACKUP;
DELETE DATAFILECOPY ALL;
```

Next **LIST BACKUP** did not found nothing.

Still, in my directories I have about 4 TB of data. Database is 8 TB.

File has names like:

- 20160226historyotqusdq7_1_1.bck
- 20151105historydata_D-**HISTDB**_I-3526265592_TS-**history_2013**_FNO-186_pmqlg4jl.bck

And so on, some hundreds of files.

HISTDB is the sid, history_2013 is one of the tablespaces.

How can I indentify **what** that files are and **clean** them in a safe way?

Oracle is version 11.2.0.2 on redhat linux, kernel version 2.6.18-238.el5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the database does not know about those files, you should catalog them in RMAN:

```
catalog start with '/path/to/files';
```

After that you can use your above commands for identifying or deleting these files.

Deleting old backups in a safe way is achieved by running `DELETE OBSOLETE`, with the required retention set in configuration or specified in the command (e.g. `DELETE OBSOLETE RECOVERY WINDOW OF 14 DAYS;`).